# Get value from cookies in database Codeigniter PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, cookies

Actually i don't know what is this case name, i save/insert cart cookies php codeigniter to database, and it successful, but i cannot get the specific value from that database string.

This is data from my DB

```
a:1:{s:32:"1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc";a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc";s:2:"id";s:1:"6";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";s:6:"275000";s:4:"name";s:10:"Vinly True";s:8:"subtotal";i:275000;}}
```

And how can i get specific value in that string? for example get "name" value "Vinly True" or price "275000".

Comment: This is a serializes object / array so you need `unserialize()` to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string is the result of a PHP `serialize()` function. Serialize creates a string from an Array or Object.

To get the Array back to a usable state in PHP you  use `unserialize()` on it

So

```
$new_array = unserialize($the_table_column_name);
$name = $new_array['name'];
```

Comment: i try your code, and give error 
$new_array = unserialize($var);
$name = $new_array['name'];
echo $name;
Message: Undefined index: name

My $var is from my database result

Comment: i got it, this is my valid code for this case, 
$name = $new_array['1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc']['name'];
this site help me very well http://www.unserialize.com